# Syntax Error In Python When Trying To Refer To Range Of Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove the last several columns from a data frame.  However I get a syntax error when I do this:

`db = db.drop(db.columns[[12:22]], axis = 1)`

This works but it seems clumsy...

`db = db.drop(db.columns[[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]], axis = 1)`

How do I refer to a range of columns?

Comment: I've never used pandas before, but I took a quick look at the documentation, and seems to be that there is not such thing as a range specifier; but if is just a list, you can use list comprehension, I guess, like this: `[i for i in range(12,23)]`

Answer (score 1):

The first example uses `[12:22]` is a "slice" of nothing.  It's not a meaningful statement, so as you say, it gives a syntax error.  It seems that what you want is a list containing the numbers 12 through 22.  You need to either write it out fully as you did, or use some generator function to create it.

The simplest is `range`, which is a generator that creates a list of sequential values.  So you can rewrite your example like:

`db = db.drop(db.columns[list(range(12,23)]], axis = 1)`

Though it looks like you are using some sort of library.  If you want more detailed control, you need to look the documentation of that library.  It seems that `db.columns` is an object of a class that has defined an array operator.  Perhaps that class's documentation shows a way of specifying ranges in a way other than a list.

Answer (score 0):

Steven Burnap's explanation is correct, but the solution can be simplified - just remove the internal parentheses:

`db = db.drop(db.columns[12:22], axis = 1)`

this way, `db.columns[12:22]` is a 'slice' of the columns array (actually index, but doesn't matter here), which goes into the `drop` method.